# Internal testing in Google Play publishes the old version of app

Tags: flutter, google-play-console, beta-testing, google-play-internal-testing

I'm trying to create *interval* test for my flutter app.
But Google Console is not publishes the new version of the app for testers.

I'm **NOT** publishing the app for the first time.
I have a previous version of the app that was approved.
However this is my first test for the app.

I strictly followed the instructions provided by Google.

What I did:

1. made a new release that I want to test
2. created internal test
3. added list of internal testers (all of them are approved now).
4. published the new version to internal test
5. copied the link and tried to get the test version of the app as an internal tester.
   However I've downloaded the old version of the app.

I've also tried to create *alpha* and *beta* testing after that and provided them with new version.
But still got this problem.

What's more, I did some extra step to solve this problem:

- cleaned Play Market cache on the device
- downloaded another simulator to test the app
- changed the version of the app and downloaded it again
- deleted and added again tester list in Google play console

Screenshots:

1. https://github.com/asg1997/qu/blob/main/Screenshot_1639590890.png
2. https://github.com/asg1997/qu/blob/main/Screenshot_1639591139.png,
3. https://github.com/asg1997/qu/blob/main/Screenshot_1639591150.png,
4. https://github.com/asg1997/qu/blob/main/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-12-15%20%D0%B2%2020.53.20.png,
5. https://github.com/asg1997/qu/blob/main/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-12-15%20%D0%B2%2020.54.18.png